# How to search for whole words in a Makefile string?

Tags: makefile

I need a method to search for a substring only if it is a whole word.

Ideally I want a function (say `findwstring()`) such that the two examples,
`$(findwstring a, a b c)`
`$(findwstring a, angle b c)`
should produce the values ‘a’ and ‘’ (the empty string), respectively.

I couldn't find anything [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) which could help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(filter a, a b c)
```

Produces `'a'`.

```
$(filter a, angle b c)
```

Produces `''`.

Percent (`%`) in the search string is considered the wildcard character.

From the docs you linked (actually the function right below `findstring`), **boldface** mine:

> ```
> $(filter pattern…,text)
> ```
>
> Returns all **whitespace-separated words** in text that *do* match any of the *pattern* words, removing any words that *do not* match. The patterns are written using ‘%’, just like the patterns used in the `patsubst` function above.
>
> The `filter` function can be used to separate out different types of strings (such as file names) in a variable. For example:
>
> ```
> sources := foo.c bar.c baz.s ugh.h
> foo: $(sources)
>         cc $(filter %.c %.s,$(sources)) -o foo
> ```
>
> says that `foo` depends of `foo.c`, `bar.c`, `baz.s` and `ugh.h` but only `foo.c`, `bar.c` and `baz.s` should be specified in the command to the compiler.